# How to show progress status then auto page redirect using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I would like to know how I can automatically hide some containers and use a timeout to show a progress status. After completion, it should perform an automatic page redirect using JavaScript. This is my approach so far:

```
<div id="processing">Processing...</div>
<div id="Phrazing...">Phrazing...</div>
<div id="Exporting">Exporting...</div>
<div id="Redirecting">Redirecting...</div>

<div id="processing">Processing...to show and disapear for certain seconds, then followed by:</div>
<div id="Phrazing...">Phrazing...to show and disapear for certain seconds, then followed by:</div>  
<div id="Exporting">Exporting...to show and disapear for certain seconds, then followed by:</div>
<div id="Redirecting">Redirecting...to show and disapear for certain second the also redirectes a web page export.html </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of `setTimeout` to show / hide element after particular time.
See below code where you can call specific function from `setTimeout` and show it sequentially

```js
$(function(){
showProcessing();
function showProcessing() {
  $('#processing').show();
 setTimeout(function(){ hideProcessing();}, 3000);
}

function hideProcessing() {
  $('#processing').hide();
   showPhrazing();
}

function showPhrazing() {
  $('#Phrazing').show();
  setTimeout(function(){ hidePhrazing();}, 3000);
}

function hidePhrazing() {
  $('#Phrazing').hide();
  showExporting();
}

function showExporting() {
  $('#Exporting').show();
  setTimeout(function(){ hideExporting();}, 3000);
}

function hideExporting() {
  $('#Exporting').hide();
  showRedirecting();
}

function showRedirecting() {
  $('#Redirecting').show();
  setTimeout(function(){ hideRedirecting();}, 3000);
}

function hideRedirecting() {
  $('#Redirecting').hide();
  setTimeout(function(){window.location = "export.html";}, 1000);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="processing" style="display:none">Processing...</div>
<div id="Phrazing" style="display:none">Phrazing...</div>  
<div id="Exporting" style="display:none">Exporting...</div>
<div id="Redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting...to export.html </div>
```

Comment: I just tried it but it's not working. Could uou please kindly review thw code for me:
https://codepen.io/chlserver/pen/yLNBjgm

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to hide all div first using `style="display:none"`, remove <script> tag from JS section of codepen as this is redundant and not required in codepen but will required in you actual html page. By making these two changes your code working for me so it should work for you. By the way, I saw you have kept timeout value as 30000 which is equal to 30 seconds, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. I will try this now

Comment: I just tried now but I guess something is wrong with code i put together it skipped the 1st - 5th div IDs and started from processing.

https://codepen.io/chlserver/pen/yLNBjgm

I'd be glad if yu can kindy check the code above on code pen is I made some mistake

Comment: code looks good to me and it is working for me. As you have setTimeout for 30000, div is getting show and hide after 30 seconds. I can see that `connecting`, `exchanging`, `Access`... etc divs but as you have called `showProcessing();` as first method inside `$(function(){` hence it is starting with Processing. If you need to start with Connecting first then call `showConnecting` instead of `showProcessing`. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Oh... I got it now/ Thank you so much

Comment: WHat if I want to apply this to a dive class lets take for an example
<div class="connecting">
Would the correct code be
 $(function(){
showConnecting();
function showConnecting() {
  $('.connecting').show();
 setTimeout(function(){ hideConnecting();}, 30000);
}

function hideConnecting() {
  $('.connecting').hide();
   showExchanging();
}

Beausse I just tried it now but its not working

do I have to include: div.connecting

Comment: Here is the new code:
https://codepen.io/chlserver/pen/QWbLRev

Comment: as i said earlier, you need to hide all divs first by putting `style="display:none"` in each div. Example `<div id="connecting" style="display:none"> Connecting... </div>`. This is required because we are showing each div after specific time interval and hiding previous one

Comment: I included it and I actially have another div class I want to pass the display js attritute to. Would the script strcuturing work for both div ID and Div class?

Comment: for div id we use `#` for selecting div and id must be unique always and it return only one HTML element. For class, we use `.` (dot) for selecting div and it may return multiple HTML elements. See this for more details - https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  and https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp. Hence code we have used with id jquery selector will not work for class